# Show that for $k= 1,2,\dots,n$, $\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}|\log(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{Nx_k})-\log(\max_{1\le k\le N}e^{Nx_k})|=0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{x_k\}_{k\ge 1}$ be a sequence of a real number.

> Questions 1: Show that for $k= 1,2,\dots,n$,
> $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N} \left|\log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{Nx_k} \right) - \log\left(\max_{1\le k\le n} e^{Nx_k}\right) \right|=0$$

> Question 2: Assume that $\sum_{k\ge 1}|x_k|$ is finite. How can we let $n$ grow with $N$ while making sure the above remains valid.

For Q1, we have
$$\frac{1}{N}|\log(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{Nx_k})-\log(\max_{1\le k\le N}e^{Nx_k})|\le \frac{1}{N}|\log(n)|\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$.

Can we say
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{1}{N}|\log(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{Nx_k})-\log(\max_{1\le k\le N}e^{Nx_k})|=0$$

For question 2:
If this is true, we can just pick $n=e^{e^N}$?

Comment: should it be $\max\limits_{1\le k\le n}$?

Comment: How does the $a_k$ in question 2 relate to question 1?

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, I have edited these typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing $x_k =0$ for all $k$, you can see that in order for the limit to converge to the desired value, the limit  $\lim \frac{\log(n(N))}{N}$ must converge to $0$ when $N$ converges to infinity. And this condition , saying
$$\lim \frac{\log(n(N))}{N} =0$$
, is also sufficient as the argument in **Q1** is also applicable in **Q2**

Comment: That is my answer, right? What is $n(N)$ in your answer? How about the Q2? I am confused about that.

Comment: No it isn't. I was answering your second question. Your question is about the growth speed of $n$, right?  So I gave you the condition for the growth speed.